# Maya Custom Push/Relax Script

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm trying to make a custom script that replicates/imitates the Maya Sculpt Geometry Tool. Basically I have 2 radio buttons, Push and Relax[which imitates the push and relax from the sculpt parameters obviously], a value slider[replicates the max displacement slider]. The radio and reset button works perfectly however I'm having problems with coding the slider. Any help for this one? Thanks in advance.

Please see images for further clarification.
[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zz5u.png)

Here is my code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel


if cmds.window("cusWin", exists = True):
    cmds.deleteUI("cusWin")



customwindow = cmds.window("cusWin",t= "Push/Relax", wh = (200, 117), s= False, mnb= False, mxb= False)
cmds.frameLayout( label='Push/Relax Modifier', borderStyle='in', cll= False)
cmds.columnLayout(adj = True, columnOffset= ("both", 3))


cmds.radioCollection()
cmds.radioButton(l = "Push", onc= "mel.eval('artUpdatePuttyOperation artPuttyCtx push ;')")
cmds.radioButton(l = "Relax", onc= "mel.eval('artUpdatePuttyOperation artPuttyCtx relax ;')")

cmds.separator(style= "none", h= 3)

DynFsgCol1 = 30
DynFsgCol2 = 50
DynFsgCol3 = 100

valSlider = cmds.floatSliderGrp(l = "Value", field = True, min = 0, max= 5, precision = 4, cw3= (DynFsgCol1, DynFsgCol2, DynFsgCol3 ))
cmds.separator(style= "none", h= 3)

cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, columnWidth=[(1,98),(2,100)], columnOffset=[(1,'left',1),(2,'right',95)])
cmds.button(l = "Apply", w= 92, c= 'slider()')
cmds.button(l = "Reset", w= 91, c= 'resetButton()')

cmds.showWindow( customwindow )


def slider():
    valueSlider = cmds.floatSliderGrp(valSlider, q= True, value= True)
    mel.eval('artPuttyCtx -e -maxdisp valueSlider `currentCtx`;')

def resetButton():
    mel.eval('resetTool artPuttyContext;')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two different things going on here.

First, by using the string form of the callbacks you lose control over the scope of your functions.  It's better to pass the python objects directly.  This version does what it looks like your's is intended to do using the callbacks:
    import maya.cmds as cmds
    import maya.mel as mel

```
if cmds.window("cusWin", exists = True):
    cmds.deleteUI("cusWin")



customwindow = cmds.window("cusWin",t= "Push/Relax", wh = (200, 117), s= False, mnb= False, mxb= False)
cmds.frameLayout( label='Push/Relax Modifier', cll= False)
cmds.columnLayout(adj = True, columnOffset= ("both", 3))


cmds.radioCollection()
push = lambda _: cmds.artPuttyCtx(cmds.currentCtx(), e = True,  mtm='push')
relax = lambda _: cmds.artPuttyCtx(cmds.currentCtx(), e = True, mtm='relax')



cmds.radioButton(l = "Push", onc= push)
cmds.radioButton(l = "Relax", onc=relax)

cmds.separator(style= "none", h= 3)

DynFsgCol1 = 30
DynFsgCol2 = 50
DynFsgCol3 = 100

valSlider = cmds.floatSliderGrp(l = "Value", field = True, min = 0, max= 5, precision = 4, cw3= (DynFsgCol1, DynFsgCol2, DynFsgCol3 ))
cmds.separator(style= "none", h= 3)
cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, columnWidth=[(1,98),(2,100)], columnOffset=[(1,'left',1),(2,'right',95)])

# put the defs here, where the names of the slider are known
def slider(*_):
    valueSlider = cmds.floatSliderGrp(valSlider, q = True, value = True)
    cmds.artPuttyCtx(cmds.currentCtx(), e = True,  maxdisp = valueSlider)

def resetButton(*_):
    cmds.resetTool(cmds.currentCtx())

cmds.button(l = "Apply", w= 92, c= slider)
cmds.button(l = "Reset", w= 91, c= resetButton)

cmds.showWindow( customwindow )
```

The thing to note is that order in which things are defined allows you to reference the names of controls you've made. (As an aside, you need to handle the nonsense arguments Maya passes on the button and slider callbacks).  It's also a good idea to clean up dangling Mel scripts where you can, if you want to make this tool more complex in future it's much harder if you have to work in two languages at once. In this case `artUpdatePuttyOperation` looks like it's defined when the sculpt tool UI opens, so if you ran this script without the UI I don't think it would work correctly.

The second issue is that you're not explicitly setting an `artPuttyCtx` with `setTool`, so this won't work unless the user has already created the right context and activated it.

Comment: Hi there sir and thanks for replying. I'm sorry about the code. I'm a beginner and still getting used to python. Is there a way for the radio buttons to work without having the need to open the sculpt tool UI? The value slider works perfectly thank you for that. However when I click the "Apply" button the value changes (which is perfect) but nothing happens to the mesh. Thanks in advance